# Пропали фото в товаре на сайте Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Товар выводится в нескольких местах на сайте - на странице бренда и в разделе "Товары", там все товары вместе собраны. Заменил фото товара в админке wordpress на вордпрессовской вкладке "товары", но фото обновились только на странице бренда, а на вкладке "товары" пропали. Как решить?

Comment: Нам гадать на кофейной гуще? Ну ок, для начала проверьте пути к файлам на вкладке "товары" и сравните с теми, что на странице бренда. По идее они должны браться из одного места, только с разным параметром "обрезалки". Во-вторых, вспомните, не меняли ли чего-нибудь в коде, может в запросе стоит выборка по параметру, который вы не учли при заливке новых фоток.

Comment: пути одинаковые

Comment: скиньте хоть адрес сайта. И что по условиям выборки из БД?

Comment: сайт http://elari.ua, там в меню разделы по брендам и вкладка "Товары". В товарах fixitime3 и kidphone2, что на странице бренда, есть фото, а в них же, в разделе "Товары" только миниатюры на корневой, в самих товарах нет ничего. Ну у кидфона 2 только розовый есть.

Comment: Все нормально у вас с товарами (кидфон2 есть синий и розовый), внутри каждого товара по несколько фотографий в галереи. Либо у вас были старые пути к этим фотографиям, либо просто обновите кэш

Comment: На вкладке "Товары" всё есть? я с хрома, жму ctrl+f5 и ctrl+shift+r, никаких изменений не происходит.

Comment: Эм... В разделе "Товары" я увидел их штук 12 или больше на 2 страницах. Может мы говорим о разных вещах?

Comment: ну да, а теперь откройте fixitime3 или kidphone 2 со страницы "Товары". И что, там есть фото?

Comment: Физически они существуют (http://elari.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/FixiTime3_black-ava.jpg). Оба этих товара имеют размеры 600 на 600, с которыми у wp/обрезалки/сервера имеются проблемы. Они у вас "на лету" режутся что ли?

Comment: в каком смысле "на лету"? интуитивно, проблема в путях, так как они как-то не состыкуются со страницей товары.

Comment: "на лету" значит их режет скрипт php, то есть физически они не существуют на жестком диске, но не думаю что wp умеет это делать. Как вариант попробуйте уменьшить размеры фоток и залить их по новой. Просто ради интереса хотя бы.